# How do I debug Flash Builder 4.7 on Windows 10?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, windows-10

I just installed Windows 10 and can no longer debug in Flash Builder 10.  I can't seem to get the debug version of Flash installed in Chrome and there's no debugger on Adobe's site for Win10.   I don't really care which browser I use to debug but I can't get any to work.   I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you tried to download it from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) ?

Comment: Yeah, nothing there for Windows 10.  I tried the chrome version too but it won't show in about:plugins.

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome 44 and windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Chrome 43 to 44 and it is fixed in 45.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=497996